# Does starting a working visa in Canada reset my ESTA?

Tags: usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, tourist-visas, french-citizens

I obtained a working visa for Canada for two years to start between April 2015 and April 2016. I am planning to work in Montreal.

I am presently visiting friends in Vermont, and have been here 60 days.

I realize that simply entering Canada will not affect my ESTA, but I wonder whether beginning my work visa in Canada will this reset my ESTA, thus allowing me to visit my friend time to time from Canada.

Also, if I leave the US to go to Canada one month before the end of my ESTA, would I be able to come back to use these 30 days another time during the year?

Comment: Which US visa do you have, or are you on ESTA? What is your citizenship?

Comment: I am on ESTA and I am french. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To clarify your terminology: The ESTA is not a visa--you are in the US on the Visa-Waiver Program.  Your question boils down to: Does entering Canada reset your ESTA? The answer is no. See [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/42194/444).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, my question is: does starting a working visa in Canada reset my ESTA?

Comment: @Flimzy Ironic that you point out the difference between ESTA and VWP and then say that the question is whether entering Canada resets your ESTA. It isn't: it's whether entering Canada resets your VWP clock. But the answer is still no.

Comment: Alright, I am going to try to make my question clearer. My question isn't about entering Canada and come back to the US to have my ESTA reset. I am aware it doesn't work. My question is about my change of status: when I will start my working visa, I will become a resident in Canada. As I changed my status, would I be able to come back in the US in the year just for short stays (visiting)?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I'm not sure what you're talking about, really... I pointed out the difference between VWP/ESTA and a visa. I didn't point out any difference between VWP and ESTA (they're mostly effectively synonymous for the purpose of this question). But that  link does answer the question clearly in the very first sentence: `The ESTA doesn't reset if you go to Mexico or Canada`.

Comment: @M38: "Does starting a working visa in Canada reset my ESTA?"  I'm pretty sure the answer is also no (US immigration basically doesn't care where you work, unless it changes your VWP eligibility--Canadian residency shouldn't change that in your case), but that is indeed a distinct question, I suppose.

Comment: @Flimzy The answer you link to also confuses ESTA and VWP. ESTA doesn't "reset": it's valid for two years (or your passport expires, if that's sooner). It's the Visa Waiver Program which limits you to being in the USA for 90 days and requires you to leave North America to reset the clock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Living in Canada - quick USA trips?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46921/living-in-canada-quick-usa-trips)

Comment: @Flimzy the 90-day clock does not reset when the traveler makes a "short trip" within North America (see http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html).  Therefore, it is possible to enter the US on VWP, leave to take up temporary residence in Canada, and then re-enter the US on the VWP.

Comment: @DavidRicherby see my previous comment: it is possible to reset the 90-day VWP limit without leaving North America.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the clarification! (And the ping.)